# Different Behaviour of pdfConverter (ephtmltopdf) on 2 Different production Servers

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

I am using an ephtmltopdf dll to convert an .aspx page to a pdf.The pdf Converter successfully converted a published page on a production server which uses Windows 2008 server and IE 8 into a pdf.But when i published the same page on another production server which uses Windows 2003 server,it showed an error

> Could not generate the PDF document. Could not render the url. Could
>   not get image from url.Navigation timeout..

I tried loading the page url which i am trying to convert to pdf in a web browser and surprisingly it loaded perfectly.First i thought may be some issue with my .aspx html code and i tested by publishing only the design of the .aspx page.And it was successfully converted.So i thought may be some issue with the c# code.So i checked my code log and surprisingly nothing seems wrong with the c# code.All c# code executed successfully.
After i bit of googling some suggested an increase in pdfconverter.Navigation timeout....so increased that too, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ephtmltopdf dll that i was using was some how corrupt i guess,since no matter what ever navigation timeout i was setting it was getting timed out after 1 min ...so i downloaded a new dll from their site .....and bingo it worked like a charm...